# How do I print a list of all variable created for a class in order in Python?

Tags: python, class, variables

I have the following class:

```
class Countries(object):
    def __init__(self, country_capital, country_population):
        self.capital = country_capital
        self.population = country_population
```

And a list of variables connected to the class:

```
france = Countries("Paris", "66")
england = Countries("London", "53")
usa = Countries("Washington, DC", "318")
germany = Countries("Berlin", "80")
```

How do I go about the Countries() Capitals in order of population?
e.g. ["London", "Paris", "Berlin", "Washington, DC"]

Comment: Side remark: I'd name the class `Country`, because you only model one country with it at a time.

Comment: I was just about to offer that suggestion until I saw your comment. Well done!

Answer (score 5):

Put your classes in a list, and sort them based on the `population` attribute (which you must convert to an integer to correctly sort):

```
[c.capital for c in sorted([france, england, usa, germany], key=lambda c: int(c.population))]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to extract *just* the capital name from each country object, after sorting those objects by population.

I used the `key` argument to the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) to tell it to sort on the `Countries.population` attribute (converted to a number with `int()`):

```
>>> class Countries(object):
...     def __init__(self, country_capital, country_population):
...         self.capital = country_capital
...         self.population = country_population
...
>>> france = Countries("Paris", "66")
>>> england = Countries("London", "53")
>>> usa = Countries("Washington, DC", "318")
>>> germany = Countries("Berlin", "80")
>>> [c.capital for c in sorted([france, england, usa, germany], key=lambda c: int(c.population))]
['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Washington, DC']
```

Or you could just, you know, manually put them in order, but I assumed you wanted the computer to do the sorting.. :-)

Comment: You have a lot of typos... it should be `[country.capital for country in sorted([france, england, usa, germany], key = lambda c: int(c.population))]`

Comment: @EddoHintoso: just `c in` was missing, plus the `t` of `int`. Oops, and thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

## DISCLAIMER

Before moving forward, I'd like to say that [Martijn Pieters♦ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698614/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-all-variable-created-for-a-class-in-order-in-python/35698672#35698672) is, to me, clearly superior because it is more efficient, readable, and understandable based on inference with English relatively to my answer.

---

## MY SOLUTION

But... just for fun, this is an alternative solution using `map`, anonymous functions, and tuples (which may or may not be highly inefficient):

```
>>> countries = [france, england, usa, germany]
>>> countries_info = map(lambda c: (c.capital, int(c.population)), countries)
>>> print countries_info
[('Paris', 66), ('London', 53), ('Washington, DC', 318), ('Berlin', 80)]
>>>
>>> capitals_by_population = map(lambda c: c[0],  # extract first elem - capital
                                 sorted(countries_info, key = lambda c: c[1]))
>>> print capitals_by_population
['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Washington, DC']
```

---

## BONUS: "BENCHMARKING"

So I'm just going to use Python's `timeit` module to see whether my solution or [Martijn Pieters♦ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698614/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-all-variable-created-for-a-class-in-order-in-python/35698672#35698672) is faster/slower.

```
from timeit import timeit

class Country(object):

    def __init__(self, country_capital, country_population):
        self.capital = country_capital
        self.population = country_population

france = Country("Paris", "66")
england = Country("London", "53")
usa = Country("Washington, DC", "318")
germany = Country("Berlin", "80")

countries = [france, england, usa, germany]

def sorted_capitals_by_population_martijn(countries):
    return [
        country.capital
        for country
        in sorted(countries, key = lambda c: int(c.population))
    ]

def sorted_capitals_by_population_eddo(countries):
    countries_info = map(lambda c: (c.capital, int(c.population)), countries)
    capitals_by_population = map(lambda c: c[0],
                                 sorted(countries_info, key = lambda c: c[1]))
    return capitals_by_population

nsim = 1 * (10 ** 6)

sort_times = {
    "martijn": timeit("sorted_capitals_by_population_martijn(countries)",
                      number=nsim,
                      setup="from __main__ import sorted_capitals_by_population_martijn, countries"),
    "eddo": timeit("sorted_capitals_by_population_eddo(countries)",
                   number=nsim,
                   setup="from __main__ import sorted_capitals_by_population_eddo, countries")
}

print(sort_times)
```

The output is below is displayed in seconds, and the results are expected:

```
{'eddo': 3.5935261249542236, 'martijn': 2.572805166244507}
```

***As stated in my disclaimer, undoubtedly pick [Martijn Pieters♦ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698614/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-all-variable-created-for-a-class-in-order-in-python/35698672#35698672) over [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698614/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-all-variable-created-for-a-class-in-order-in-python/35699584#35699584)!***